# How to run maven test in docker-compose run after docker-compose -d?

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I am creating a CI/CD pipeline in GitLab. Using spring boot and Postgres.
This is the docker-compose file.

```
version: '2'

services:
  backend-api:
    container_name: backend-api
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres
      DB_HOST: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
      DB_USERNAME: postgres
    image: myimagepath
    ports:
      - 8080:8080/tcp
    restart: always

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432/tcp
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - myvolumepath
```

I want to run tests after docker-compose up.

```
docker-compose up -d backend-api postgres && sleep 30
```

After this command `docker-compose ps` shows that these two services are running.

```
docker-compose run backend-api mvn test
```

This command starts the application on port 8080 and does not run the tests. How do you run tests after docker-compose in the backgorund without starting the application?

Comment: Why do you combine gitlab and docker-compose?

Comment: I am creating a multi-stage pipeline in GitLab.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to check https://www.testcontainers.org/